# Youtube video in Webview and listview using React Native

Tags: android, listview, react-native, webview, youtube

I am new in React native. I am facing problem of Youtube videos are playing with audio only. Below is code that I am using now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {
   View,
   ListView,
   WebView,
   StyleSheet,
   ScrollView
}
from 'react-native'

 url=[
    {
    "videourl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZnvJvZAJZPk",
    },
    {
    "videourl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/HOI8nlFa86U",
    },
    {
    "videourl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0bDI_rAMV68",
    },
    ]

class WebViewExample extends Component{

  constructor (props) {
    super (props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(url),
    };
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
        renderRow={this.renderRows.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
  renderRows(rowData){
    console.log("url: "+rowData.videourl);
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{borderWidth:3, borderColor : '#FF0000', flex:1}}>
          <WebView source={{uri: rowData.videourl}} style={{}} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default WebViewExample;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      height: 350,
   }
})
```

React native version:0.47

Comment: I am able to see the video on the mobile device. It's may be the Expo is not supporting the video.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your responses. I am using the android emulator to test. But still plays the audio only.

Answer (score 1):

Though the code is correct, it will throw error as you have to mention `url` as a `const`

```
const url=[
    {
    "videourl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZnvJvZAJZPk",
    },
    {
    "videourl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/HOI8nlFa86U",
    },
    {
    "videourl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0bDI_rAMV68",
    },
    ];
```

Check the [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/S1KdNErcb)

Note: Video won't display in the Expo Web version, but you will be able to see it in the Mobile Version.

Comment: your blood is worth bottling  :)

Comment: After I add "const" also facing same problem.

Comment: I guess it's the emulator. As I am unable to see on my emulator but when I put the same code on my phone. Video is perfectly fine. So try using the same code on the mobile device. Check [this link](https://snack.expo.io/S1KdNErcb)